# Python:Error al sumar todos los valores de una columna de un query

Tags: python

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de sumar la columna de una tabla creada por Python y el módulo peewee:

Así he creado la tabla:

```
    from peewee import SqliteDatabase, Model, CharField

    db = SqliteDatabase('coches.db')


    class Coche (Model):
        Marca = CharField()
        Modelo = CharField()
        Precio = CharField()
        Numero_vendidos = CharField()
        Gama = CharField()

        class Meta:
            database = db

    db.connect()
    db.create_tables([Coche]) #el modelo de datos, lo que va a contener
    db.close()
```

y en otro archivo de python he añadido mis datos:

```
   from Modulo_10.exe1 import Coche


   listado_coches_tupla = [

    ('Ford', 'Fiesta', '9000', '1000', 'Baja'),

   ('Ford', 'Focus', '14500', '540', 'Media'),

    ('Ford', 'Mondeo', '28000', '630', 'Alta'),

    ('Citroen', 'C3', '9500', '780', 'Baja'),

    ('Citroen', 'C4', '13500', '340', 'Media'),

    ('Citroen', 'C5', '26000', '120', 'Alta'),

    ('Peugeot', '208', '9700', '1250', 'Baja'),

    ('Peugeot', '308', '16000', '160', 'Media'),

    ('Peugeot', '408', '27500', '1760', 'Alta')

   ]


   Coche.insert_many(listado_coches_tupla, fields=[Coche.Marca, Coche.Modelo, Coche.Precio,
                                            Coche.Numero_vendidos, Coche.Gama]).execute()
```

Una vez creados intento sumar la columna Numeros vendidos con esta función:

```
    for coche in Coche.select(Coche.Numero_vendidos):
        valor=sum(int(coche.Numero_vendidos))
        print(valor)
```

no logro imprimir el valor total de la suma por lo que me da este error:

```
  valor=sum(int(coche.Numero_vendidos))
  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Soy nuevo en este lenguaje y me gustaría saber en que parte me estoy equivocando
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues la operación `sum()` es una operación **reduce** es decir tienes un conjunto de números, por ejemplo una lista, y sumas todos los números que hay en esa lista, ejemplo:

```
lista_1 = [1,2,3,4]

sum(lista_1)
```

**Salida:** `10`

Lo que te ocurre es que `coche.Numero_vendidos` no es una **colección**, es un simple número que representa la cantidad de coches vendidos. Por lo que es como si estuvieras haciendo:

```
sum(5)
```

**Salida:** `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Objtengo el mismo error que tú, ya que el número cinco no es una colección de *N* elementos en la que vas sumando *x1 +x2 +x3 .... xn*, si no que es un simple número, por lo que el error en Español sería:

"No puedo iterar a traves de un número entero"

### Solución

una vez llegads aquí lo que puedes hacer es almacenar las cantidades de los distintos coches en una lista utilizado el método `.append()`, y posteriormente, aplicar la función `sum()` a dicha lista:

```
#Creamos una lista vacia
coches_vendidos = []

for coche in Coche.select(Coche.Numero_vendidos):
    coches_vendidos.append(int(coche.Numero_vendidos))

print(sum(coches_vendidos))
```

Comment: Gracias Alberto, pero esa función ya la realicé y no me suma los valores de la columna, ¿Cómo puedo sumarlos?

Comment: Solo te solucione el error, para que no te diera el `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`, te he actualizado la respuesta, con la solución completa.

Comment: Gracias Alberto, la opción de usar la función append para cambiar el formato y almacenarlo en una lista para después sumarlos no la conocía. Muchas gracias